# Rails 3: How do I validate to allow blanks ("") but not nil (NULL in database)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In an ActiveRecord (or ActiveModel) I would like the following spec to pass

```
it { should allow_value("").for(:my_string) }
it { should_not allow_value(nil).for(:my_string) }
```

I have tried

```
validates :my_string, {
  :length => { :in => 0..255 },
  :presence => true,
  :allow_blank => true,
  :allow_nil => false,
}
```

and also

```
validates :my_string, {
  :length => { :in => 0..255 },
  :allow_blank => true,
  :allow_nil => false,
}
```

But either it allows both "" and nil or none of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might need to do a custom validation for this:

```
validates :my_string, :length => { :in => 0..255 }
validate :my_string_is_valid

def my_string_is_valid
  self.errors.add :base, 'My string can not be nil' if self.my_string.nil? 
end
```

Comment: This is what I have done... However I find it strange that Rails does not support this situation.

Answer (score 40):

This works for me

```
  validates :my_string, length: { in: 0..255, allow_nil: false }
```

If you just want to validate that the field is not null, but don't care about blank/empty strings, this works:

```
  validates :my_string, length: { minimum: 0, allow_nil: false, message: "can't be nil" }
```

Answer (score 15):

You can try doing:

```
validates :my_string, exclusion: { in: [nil]}
```

It is part of the validations themselves in ActiveRecord.

I've tried the others and all of them are very compliated or allow nil too.

Comment: It stopped working after I upgraded to rails 6.1

Answer (score 3):

You can create a simple custom validator (placed in `app/validators` dir)

```
class NotNilValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors[attribute] << "must not be nil" if value.nil?
  end
end
```

and then

```
validates :my_string, not_nil: true
```

Comment: This can also be written as `record.errors.add(attribute, 'must not be nil) if value.nil?`

Comment: Wilson's answer is missing the closing quote. It should be `record.errors.add(attribute, 'must not be nil') if value.nil?`

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe:

```
validates :my_string, :length => { :in => 0..255 }, :allow_nil => false
```

Seems that `allow_nil` does not override `allow_blank`.
So you better no specify `allow_blank`

Comment: trying out your suggestion, makes `it { should_not allow_value(nil).for(:my_string) }` fail.

Comment: when you have `presence: true, allow_blank: true, allow_nil: false` at the same time. It will allow nil

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
validates_exclusion_of :my_string, in: [nil]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please add a few words to help explain your answer?