# How to accept blanks but not nulls in Rails 4 model validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have strings to store in the database, and I want to accept empty strings, but not null values.  This is why I can't use the rails presence validator.

I've read an answer to this question for rails 3 from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395743/rails-3-how-do-i-validate-to-allow-blanks-but-not-nil-null-in-database), but I wasn't sure if that answer also applied to rails 4.  Is there anything in rails 4 that might solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think, it should work for Rails 4 as well. Try this:

```
validates :email, presence: {allow_blank: true, allow_nil: false }
```

Thanks

Comment: for some reason why I create a new object with the attr as nil, the valid? still returns true.