# rails can't read JSON request with "false" value as attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Well, I'm building a RESTfull API using rails 4.2.6 and ruby 2.3.0.
I've an **:programs** resources and whenever I try to make an POST request through **Google Postman**, I'm receiving a "can't be blank" error.
Wait, let me illustrate...

When I send this, through Postman:

```
{
  "program": {
    "expiration_points": "false"
  }
}
```

I'm getting back this:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "expiration_points": [
      "can't be blank"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've already tried: "false", 'false', false and :false.

But it works fine, when I make the POST request with "true" or true value for the **expiration_points**.

Remembering that I've defined a **default: false** value for the **expiration_points** attribute on migration.

So... The question is, what I'm doing wrong? Thanks btw.

Comment: what kind of validation do you have?

Comment: Hey @maxpleaner, I've **validates :expiration_points, presence: true** on the Program model.

Comment: @muistooshort it returns: **false**.

Comment: the accepted answer works but you could also keep the `presence: true` in your validation if you add  `allow_false: true`

Comment: @muistooshort actually im wrong. i was thinking of [allow_blank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395743/rails-3-how-do-i-validate-to-allow-blanks-but-not-nil-null-in-database), which is for empty strings. my bad. Seem you can also use [unless](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html) with a proc. Alas, it's just another way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have this in your model:

```
validates :expiration_points, presence: true
```

So what does `presence: true` do? We could check the [`validates` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates) but that just says:

> This method is a shortcut to all default validators and any custom validator classes ending in 'Validator'. Note that Rails default validators can be overridden inside specific classes by creating custom validator classes in their place such as PresenceValidator.
>   [...]

but that just gives us a bunch of examples and tells us what *some* of the options do. You could look for `PresenceValidator` documentation but there's no such thing.

If you'd been using Rails for awhile, you'd know that

```
validate :f, :presence => true
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
validates_presence_of :f
```

and the [`validates_presence_of` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_presence_of) is still around:

> Validates that the specified attributes are not blank (as defined by `Object#blank?`).
>   [...]
>   If you want to validate the presence of a boolean field (where the real values are `true` and `false`), you will want to use `validates_inclusion_of :field_name, in: [true, false]`.
>
> This is due to the way `Object#blank?` handles boolean values: `false.blank? # => true`.

So you don't want `presence: true` at all, you want to use `in: [ true, false ]` instead:

```
validate :expiration_points, :in => [ true, false ]
```